# how do I use put with a numeric?

Tags: sas

```
data _null_;
    put "hello world"; 
 run;
```

will print `hello world` to the console.

but

```
data _null_;
put 1; 
run;
```

gives me

```
Encountered " "put" "put "" at line 2, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
<EOF> 
";" ...
"*" ...
"data" ...
"proc" ...
(and 41 more)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data _null_;
put "1";
run;
```

You put text to the console.  Therefore, "1" and 1 are identical, practically speaking.  You cannot put unformatted numbers, only formatted (ie, text).  Even putting a numeric variable would work that way:

```
data _null_;
x=1;
put x;
run;
```

That actually puts the number 1 formatted with `BEST1.` format (you can override the format if you choose).